# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un mock de un método de clase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy trabajando con unos unittests y me encuentro con que quiero hacer un mock de un método de clase.

Por ejemplo, quiero hacer un mock del método `mi_metodo()` perteneciente a la clase `MiClase`.

He intentado con el decorator `patch`:

```
@patch('MiClase.mi_metodo')
def test_cualquier_cosa(self, mock_mi_metodo):
    mock_mi_metodo.return_value = None
```

Pero no me está funcionando. ¿Cómo debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clave está en usar [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) → `@patch.object(NombreDeLaClase, 'nombre_del_método')`.

```
from mock import patch

from modulo.bla import MiClase

@patch.object(MiClase, 'mi_metodo')
def test_cualquier_cosa(self, mock_mi_metodo):
    mock_mi_metodo.return_value = None
```

Si quieres que el método sea sustituido por otro que has creado tú *ad hoc*, utiliza el tercer parámetro de `patch.object` y deja de pasar el objeto *patcheado* como argumento del método:

```
def metodo_ad_hoc(self):
    # cosas en lugar de 'mi_metodo'
    return True

@patch.object(MiClase, 'mi_metodo', metodo_ad_hoc)
def test_cualquier_cosa(self):    # ¡ojo! ya no pasamos mock_mi_metodo
    # cosas ...
```

<sub>Basado en las respuestas a [Using mock patch to mock an instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8469680/1983854).</sub>